# How do I iterate through nodes within an XML XDocument, and if they meet a condition then delete them

Tags: linq-to-xml

I'm looking for guidance for the following question. I'm attempting to loop through all nodes from the parent node, id_Entries as depicted below:

```html
<id_Entries>
  <id_14222>"2020-01-21"</id_14222>
  <id_1451222>"2020-06-21"</id_1451222>
  <id_141222>"2018-06-21"</id_141222>
  <id_151222>"2019-06-21"</id_151222>
  <id_145122>"2021-06-21"</id_145122>
  <id_145222>"2020-04-21"</id_145222>
  <id_451222>"2020-01-21"</id_451222>
  <id_14512>"2020-02-21"</id_14512>
</id_Entries>
```

Within the loop, I have a couple lines of code grabbing the date and a condition that if the current date is longer than a certain amount, then I would delete that child node.

The issue I'm having is that the nodes don't get deleted.

Here is what I currently have:

```html
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);

                foreach (var child in doc.Element("id_Entries").Elements())
                {
                    string entry = (string)child;
                    entry = entry.Substring(1, entry.Length - 2);
                    string[] splitDate = entry.Split('-');
                    DateTime entryDate = new DateTime(Int32.Parse(splitDate[0]), Int32.Parse(splitDate[1]), Int32.Parse(splitDate[2]));

                    int days = (currentDate - entryDate).Days;

                    if (days >= maxDays)
                        child.Remove();
                }

                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                using (TextWriter writer = new StringWriter(builder))
                {
                    doc.Save(writer);
                }
```

From researching, I learned that you cannot remove a node during iteration. I'm unsure of what other solution there is at the moment.

Thank you fellas.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. When iterating through the list, add .ToList() at the end. From my understanding, I believe this will remove the nodes because we're currently not looping through the actual elements and are therefore able to delete the current nodes in the list.

CAUTION: This solution was simple, which is why I implemented it. There are far better solutions which yield better run times.